# Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int')

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuinteger

Xcode reports me the following warning:

> Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int')

The line which produces this warning is:

```
 NSUInteger radius = // some value;
 vImage_Buffer effectOutBuffer;

vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&effectInBuffer, &effectOutBuffer, NULL, 0, 0, radius, radius, 0, kvImageEdgeExtend);
```

**How do I get rid of this warning?**

Comment: Do an explicit conversion, aka a cast.

Comment: You fix it by using the proper data type for the parameters.

Comment: Which type is wrong?